# element alignment at document.write

Tags: javascript, html

i have the simple code below and when i run it the

element is Aligned to the center but when i open it in a window and use document.write it goes without the defined style/alignment

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>



<p align="Center">This is a p element<br>

This is also a p element.<br>

This is also a p element - Click the button to open a doc.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        win = window.open();
        win.document.open();
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            win.document.write(x[i].innerHTML);
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

---

[image]

---

any idea how to keep the original format of the HTML while writing into another document ?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> any idea how to keep the original format of the HTML while writing
>   into another document ?

You need to write `outerHTML` instead of `innerHTML` since `align=center` is the attribute of `p` which forms the outer part of the mark-up (`innerHTML` won't have it)

```
 win.document.write(x[i].outerHTML);
```

Answer (score 1):

it is normal because innerHTML take the html inside the element but not the attributes of the element. So as "center" is an attribute it is not taken and so not centered.